# "No COMPONENT named markup://aura:method found" when saving component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-design-system, aura-attribute

I get the error message "No COMPONENT named markup://aura:method found" when saving the following component. I attempted to add a simple                     `<aura:method></aura:method>` element below. I'm unsure why it would be unable to find the component if it is a standard aura component.

```
<aura:component controller="CashMatchingController">
    <aura:attribute name="invoiceLines" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cashEntryLineId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cashEntryLines" type="CashMatchingController.AvailableCashDecorator[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="paying" type="Decimal" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="availableCash" type="Decimal" default="5000"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cashAlert" type="String" default="belowAmount"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:AddToPaymentEvent" action="{!c.addToPayment}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:SubtractFromPaymentEvent" action="{!c.subtractFromPayment}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:ClearAllEvent" action="{!c.setPaymentToZero}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:AccountSelectedEvent" action="{!c.initializeData}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:CashEntryLineChangedEvent" action='{!c.changeAvailableCash}'/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="notEnoughCash" type="c:NotEnoughCashEvent"/>
    <div class="slds-tabs--scoped">
        <ul class="slds-tabs--scoped__nav" role="tablist">
            <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-heading--label slds-active" title="Item One" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--scoped__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-scoped-1" id="tab-scoped-1__item">Cash Entry Lines</a></li>
            <li class="slds-tabs--scoped__item slds-text-heading--label" title="Item Two"
                role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs--scoped__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-2" id="tab-scoped-2__item">Available Cash</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-scoped-1" class="slds-tabs--scoped__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-1__item">
            <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <table class="slds-text-body--small">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th class="table-headers">
                            Ref #
                        </th>
                        <th class="table-headers">
                            Check Date
                        </th>
                        <th class="table-headers">
                            Original Value
                        </th>
                        <th class="table-headers">
                            Current Value
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <aura:method></aura:method>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.cashEntryLines}" var="cashEntryLine" indexVar="i">

                        <c:CashEntryLineComponent cashId="{!cashEntryLine.cashId}"
                                                  cashDate="{!cashEntryLine.cashDate}"
                                                  accountReference="{!cashEntryLine.accountReference}"
                                                  cashOriginalValue="{!cashEntryLine.cashOriginalValue}"
                                                  cashCurrentValue="{!cashEntryLine.cashCurrentValue}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </table>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <br/>
            <div class="slds-text-heading--small">Paying: <span class='{!v.cashAlert}'><ui:outputCurrency value="{!v.paying}"/></span></div>
            <br/>
            <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected">
                Apply this cash entry line
            </ui:button>
        </div>
    <div id="tab-scoped-2" class="slds-tabs--scoped__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-2__item">Item Two Content</div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the below error if the `<aura:method/>` is not an direct child of `<aura:component/>`

> No COMPONENT named markup://aura:method found” when saving component

```
<aura:component>
   <div>
      <aura:method></aura:method> //ERROR
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Placing it as the direct child of `<aura:component/>`, solves the issue.

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:method name="test"></aura:method> //since name is required.
   <div>
    // code
   </div>
</aura:component>
```